# Unable to store stream data in variable in Arduino programming

Tags: arduino

I'm unable to store the `serial.port` value in a variable. I want to send a message from Android telnet app, on and off. If on comes I want to print fan on, if off comes I want to print off. I'm able to print on and off while I'm statically fixing value. I'm unable to  store the stream in a variable.

```
String stringOne;
void setup() {
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }
  // send an intro:
  Serial.println("\n\nString  substring():");
  Serial.println();
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(13,LOW);
  // Set up a String:
  stringOne ="+IPD 0,14 :ON";
  int length =  stringOne.length();
  Serial.println(stringOne.length());
  Serial.println(stringOne);
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    // substring(index) looks for the substring from the index position to the end:
    if (stringOne.substring(length-2,length) == "ON") {
      Serial.println("FAN  ON");
      digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
      // delay(2000);
    }
    if (stringOne.substring(length-3,length) == "OFF") {
      Serial.println("FAN  OFF");
      digitalWrite(13,LOW);
      // delay(2000);
    }
  }
  // you can also look for a substring in the middle of a string:
  // do nothing while true:
  while (true);
}
```

Comment: what result are you getting?

Comment: im getting  ="+IPD 0,14 :ON" in serial port , by this message i have to on and off the pin 13.

Answer (score 1):

Well, while editing your question, I couldnt help noticing that infinite loop at the end of your code.

```
// do nothing while true:
while(true)
```

In this case, even if your code was all right, you cant expect to get next data.

```
void loop --> Remember it is itself a infinite loop
```

***update 1:***

your logic to use the serial port is wrong;

**Remember, serial port only recieves a single character at a time.**
if you send "hello" from pc, at the other end, arduino will recieve h, e, l, l, o

The trick is to collect all letters into a array. and then use our logic in it.

```
char commandbuffer[20]; //an array to hold our characters
    int i=0;
     if (Serial.available() > 0) {
      while( Serial.available() >0) {  //read until all data we send arrives
        char c = Serial.read();
        commandbuffer[i]= c;  //we are actually storing it one by one
        i++;
     }
    }
    commandbuffer[i]='\n';
    for(int j = 0; j<i; j++){
      Serial.print(commandbuffer[j]);// and show it one by one too
      }
```

now when you send "hello", it will print hello back. I hope this give you some idea. Happy coding.